# How catch java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly-8, connection-reset

I have debug this exception and I observed that When user send some request to server and before server response to user, and if user close browser window Or just close that specific page then that Exception occurs.

```
2015-03-19 12:04:40 DEBUG io:132 - Error reading request
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.read(NioSocketConduit.java:282)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:130)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:108)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:49)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:88)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:539)
```

Please Help me to handle this type of exception because when this exception occurs 4 to 5 times then Server goes into not responding state.

My Environment is:
Application Server : WildFly 8.2.0.Final
Java Version:   8
JSF Version: 2.2